# Extract Hour From "yyyymmddHH"

Tags: r

This is probably asked many times but I couldn't find related resource and just can't get it right. I have a data frame with an `HourStamp` column in `yyyymmddHH` format and I need to extract the `HH` from it. How can I do it?

As an example:

```
HourStamp  Hour
2013050100   00
2013050101   01
2013050102   02
...
```

I need that `Hour` column added. Thanks!

Comment: Isn't that a simple substring operation? like `substr(hourstamp, 9, 10)`

Comment: @KlausByskovPedersen That is correct. I was thinking of `as.POSIXct` + `format` thing.

Comment: Or use dates: `format(as.POSIXct(as.character(HourStamp), format='%Y%m%d%H'), '%H')`

Comment: @Justin This is probably more of what I'm looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Like @Klaus already commented, in this case a simple substr would to the trick, i.e. `substr('2013050100', 9, 10)`. Remember that `substr` is vectorized so you can simply do:

```
df$Hour = substr(df$HourStamp, 9, 10)
```

A more flexible and powerful way of dealing with dates/times is to simply convert `HourStamp` into a real R date object:

```
d = strptime('2013050100', format = '%Y%m%d%H')
strftime(d, '%H')
[1] "00"
```

In this case the `strptime` solution is a bit cumbersome, but it allows for stuff like:

```
> strftime(d, '%A %d of %B in the year %Y')
[1] "Wednesday 01 of May in the year 2013"
```

or:

```
strftime(d, 'file%Y%d.csv')
[1] "file201301.csv"
```

or in vectorized form for your example:

```
df$time = strptime(df$HourStamp, format = '%Y%m%d%H')
df$Hour = strftime(df$time, '%H')
```